# Reload Vim highlight setting and colorscheme

Tags: vim

If I change Vim's `highlight` setting, how do I "reload" it for colorschemes to take effect?

So, in my case, I remove `highlight`'s cursor line number—

```
se hl-=N:CursorLineNr
```

Changing `highlight` from—

> highlight=8:SpecialKey,@:NonText,d:Directory,e:ErrorMsg,i:IncSearch,l:Search,m:Mor
>       eMsg,M:ModeMsg,n:LineNr,**N:CursorLineNr**,r:Question,s:StatusLine,S:StatusLineNC,c:Vert
>       Split,t:Title,v:Visual,V:VisualNOS,w:WarningMsg,W:WildMenu,f:Folded,F:FoldColumn,A:D
>       iffAdd,C:DiffChange,D:DiffDelete,T:DiffText,>:SignColumn,-:Conceal,B:SpellBad,P:Spel
>       lCap,R:SpellRare,L:SpellLocal,+:Pmenu,=:PmenuSel,x:PmenuSbar,X:PmenuThumb,*:TabLine,
>       #:TabLineSel,_:TabLineFill,!:CursorColumn,.:CursorLine,o:ColorColumn

To

> highlight=8:SpecialKey,@:NonText,d:Directory,e:ErrorMsg,i:IncSearch,l:Search,m:Mor
>       eMsg,M:ModeMsg,n:LineNr,r:Question,s:StatusLine,S:StatusLineNC,c:VertSplit,t:Title,v
>       :Visual,V:VisualNOS,w:WarningMsg,W:WildMenu,f:Folded,F:FoldColumn,A:DiffAdd,C:DiffCh
>       ange,D:DiffDelete,T:DiffText,>:SignColumn,-:Conceal,B:SpellBad,P:SpellCap,R:SpellRar
>       e,L:SpellLocal,+:Pmenu,=:PmenuSel,x:PmenuSbar,X:PmenuThumb,*:TabLine,#:TabLineSel,_:
>       TabLineFill,!:CursorColumn,.:CursorLine,o:ColorColumn

(I've emphasized the change.)

But the cursor line number is still "highlighted"!

Changing `highlight` doesn't update the colorscheme—so how do I "force" an update? I've tried setting syntax coloring off then on again and changing colorschemes to no avail.

(Cross-posted from [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14213381/reload-vim-highlight-setting-and-colorscheme).)

Answer (score 4):

Your settings look very unreadable and mashed together. Is this your `.vimrc` file? If so you can reload it with

```
:source $MYVIMRC
```

or if it's some config file your `.vimrc` doesn't select for you, you can source that file directly as

```
:source ~/.vim/path/to/configfile.vim
```

or similar.